# Urns, Balls, & Cards.

Tags: probability

We got 3 identical urns, with following content of white and black marbles:

U1: 20W and 10B

U2: 10W and 10B

U3: 10W and 30B

We draw a card at random from a deck. If a diamond **or** heart is drawn, we pick from U1. If a club is drawn, we pick from U2, and finally if a spade is drawn, we pick from U3.

Now, ***we know a white marble is picked***. What is the probability that a diamond was drawn?

**Solution Attempt**:

A: "A white ball is picked".

B: "A diamond was drawn"

Obviously we need P(B|A) = [P(A|B)*P(B)]/P(A).

P(B) was obviously 13/52. Furthermore, P(A|B) is simply 2/3, because if a diamond was drawn, we are forced to pick from U1.
Now, regarding P(A), the answer is not so simple. I can **naively** state P(A) is the total number of white balls divided by total number of balls, but I'm pretty sure we can state such a thing in a more rigorous way (decomposition?).

EDIT: Uhm, I'm pretty convinced that the above statement is wrong. Indeed, the "weight" of U1 is somehow augmented by the fact we pick from it when we draw diamond or heart.
So I'm pretty convinced we gotta use the total probability theorem, but I don't understand in which way..

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: To calculate $P(A)$ you have to go the long way, with 
$$
P(A) = P(A|\text{red card})\cdot P(\text{red card}) + P(A|\text{spades})\cdot P(\text{spades}) + P(A|\text{clubs})\cdot P(\text{clubs})
$$
Otherwise, your argument about $P(B)$ and $P(A|B)$ seems solid.

Comment: This because Cards do partition the entire sample space, right? So we do slight modification and work this way: A remains the same, but B(i) indicates a card from i-th colour. So, we apply bayes formula, as you done. THANKS! [ you can state your comment as answer, so I can accept it ].